# Matching the text using Text match in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, console

I have struggle how can I output the given text using javascript below,

What I tried is just like this but I can't get the result of two output below

```
 let result = text.match(/?????/g);
```

```js
let text = "01110010100111101000111";
let result = text.match(/01/g); //Just this line only
console.log(result);
```

First question how can I get the output should like this in console using the code above :

```
Output = 
'01','','10','0101','','01','','','01010','','01','','',''
```

and second question how can I get also output like this using the code above

```
Output = '01110010100111101000'
```

Comment: You only have one `console.log()` why do you expect more than one output?

Comment: It's not clear what the logic is for the output you want. Please explain how that output comes from the input you show.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your response how can I modify this? just this line and output it on console `let result = text.match(/?????/g); `

Comment: How should anyone know? You haven't explained what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated above, do you have any idea?

Comment: The update doesn't explain anything. All you've done is show one example without any explanation of what it means.

Comment: What do you mean by "the other one"?

Comment: @Barmar The missing code in order to get the result of each output  `text.match(/?????/g);`

Comment: You don't get it. You haven't explained how the desired output relates to the input. I don't see any pattern in it.

Comment: @Barmar I have two questions how can I get the result of the first output ? and the second output how can also I get the result ? they are separated

Comment: `console.log("Output = 
'01','','10','0101','','01','','','01010','','01','','',''")` will get the first output.

Comment: How you want to be the result from this? please explain more as @Barmar is asking for explanation.

Comment: What i understand is @marivicvaldehueza want the result should be ["0111", "01", "01", "01111", "01", "0111"]

Comment: `text.match(/(10)+1?|(01)+0?/g)` would come close to the first output.

Comment: @Alamgir Khan Please see this line `let result = text.match(/?????/g);`  how can I get the output using text.match the question mark explain what code should put there

Comment: @Jasper Habicht it almost there but I have also the single quote after the number ? where should I put?

Comment: @marivicvaldehueza You need to make clear what the logic of the regular expression is. It is not at all clear to me why there should be empty matches in between. Therefore I can only get you a result for the other parts of which the logic seems to be that it should match alternating 1 and 0 in either order (but maybe not, looking at the last part of the string).

Comment: @JasperHabicht, Im sorry to clear out the output you've given is just like this `['01', '10', '010', '10', '01', '101', '01']`    the output must like this and I think it's almost there sorry for being not clear `'01','','10','0101','','01','','','01010','','01','','',''` Im asking help if do you have idea getting also the single quote/char  ?

Comment: @marivicvaldehueza It is fully clear to me what you want the output to me. But I fear nobody is able to help you, because nobody understands the logic of the regular expression you are looking for. So, you need to explain to us the logic, *not* the output.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht Sorry for being not clear and honestly Im a newbie in programming especially in javascript ,  just trying here if can someone understand and help even Im a newbie and it's okay for me if there's no one because I lack communicating and logic skills I think I just quit this problem.